# Dynamically changing icon [QT/c++]

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic, icons

I would like to implement a dynamically changing performance tray icon in `Qt`.
However I can't seem to find any relevant link on google, so do you have any idea how to do this?

If you don't know what I'm asking for, I've created a gif file, where you'll get my idea.

So any links,codes,examples are appreciated.
http://gifninja.com/animatedgifs/715636/icon.gif

**EDIT**

So I come up with some code, but it's not working, could you please have a look at it?

**mainwindow.h**

```
QPixmap test;
QSystemTrayIcon *speedPerformance;
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

then in mainwindow constructor I have:

```
this->test = QPixmap(16,16);
```

then I call this piece of code:

```
QTimer *trayIconTimer = new QTimer(this);
connect(trayIconTimer , SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateSpeedIcon()));
trayIconTimer->start(2000); // update it every 2 seconds
```

then I create the trayicon

```
speedPerformance = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
QPainter p(&test);
QColor color;
p.fillRect(0,0,16,16,color.black());
p.end();
speedPerformance->setIcon(QIcon(test));
```

and finally, here is the code of `updateSpeeIcon()`, which is called every 2 seconds:

```
QPainter p(&test);
QColor color;
p.setPen(color.red());
xPaint+=3;
qDebug() << xPaint;
p.fillRect(xPaint,0,2,16,color.red());
p.end();
speedPerformance->setIcon(QIcon(test));
```

so, besides the fact that this code gives me segmentation fault when I try to quit the program by clicking on other trayicon which is installed, the resultant tray icon is 16x16 black square, and there are never those red filled rectangle that I'm trying to draw, do you know what can be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution is to use a [`QTimer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QTimer.html). You have to connect the [`timeout`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#timeout) signal with a slot where you will update the icon.

```
QTimer *trayIconTimer = new QTimer(this);
connect(trayIconTimer , SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateTrayIcon()));
timer->start(2000); // update it every 2 seconds
```

In your slot you will create the new icon and set it:

```
voi updateTrayIcon()
{
     QIcon newIcon = CreateIcon();
     // I assume that tray is a pointer to the `QSystemTrayIcon` 
     tray->setIcon(newIcon);
}
```

Comment: Okay, when i thought about it,i came to the same conclusion, but now ill have to programically create and draw the icon and that will probably be pain in the ass.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a tray icon, you must have used the `QSystemTrayIcon` class already. With this class you can change the tray icon at any time. Simply call `QSystemTrayIcon::setIcon()`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, these are the steps that you should follow;

```
inside your application class,
    create a icon variable
    create a dataSource variable

    inside constructor()
        icon = DEFAULT_ICON
        connect(dataSource, SIGNAL(performanceChanged()), 
                 this, SLOT(updateIcon()));

    inside updateIcon()
        var = dataSource.getPerformanceLevel();
        switch(var)
            case LEVEL_1:
                icon = getLevel1Icon()
            case LEVEL_2:
                icon = getLevel2Icon()
            ....
```

hope this helps...

Comment: Hi, this looks quite nice, but i have really many performance levels... i am measuring typing speed, and it can go from 0 to 200 at top. :/

Comment: So, then write a function that calculates color values (RGB) for the performance.